# unique ODE solution

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

If $\alpha$ > 0, and $y(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb R$ be a solution of the initial value problem $$y^\prime(x)=|1-\sin(y(x))|^{\alpha}, y(0)=0$$
How do I know for which $\alpha\gt 0$, $y(x)$ is unique?

I tried $$y'(x) = \sqrt{(1-\sin(y(x)))^2}$$ and then $$\int_{0}^{y(x)} \frac 1 {(1-\sin(s))^{\alpha /2}} \,ds $$
Bur I am not sure how to precede.

Comment: Do you know Picard-Lindelöf theorem?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net just checked it but I don't see how to use it, looks like the df(x,y)/dx is continuous. Also if $\alpha$ = 1 then we make it disappear when we differentiate. Still not sure though what is the answer

Comment: You need to check if the integral remains finite at the singularities of the integrand. If yes, then you can reach the constant solutions in finite time from a point outside them.

Answer (score 0):

The map

$$y \mapsto \lvert 1- \sin y \rvert^\alpha$$ is continuously differentiable on the interval $I=(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. Therefore it is locally Lipschitz and we can apply Picard-Lindelöf theorem around zero and conclude that the given Initial Value Problem has a unique local solution satisfying $y(0)=0$.

Comment: The last claim is wrong in some cases. If $\frac\pi2$ can be reached in finite time, then the solution can also branch away from this constant solution at an arbitrary later time. Local solutions on a small enough interval are unique, maximal solutions need not be unique.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Indeed, I need to revise last sentence, which I did. Unicity of maximal solution requires additional elements.

Comment: Yes, this is now correct, but no longer an answer to the task. There it asks about uniqueness of solutions with domain $\Bbb R$.